# generate phpDoc from url call

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm trying to create php doc from phpDocumentor 2.5.0.
I've uploaded everything on the server I'm devlopping on and I try to generate tje doc my an url call to http://website.com/phpDocumentor-2.5.0/bin/phpdoc.php

but this generate a 5OO Internal Server error. The logs tells this :

```
malformed header from script. Bad header=Collecting files .. OK: phpdoc.php
```

The online docs often refers to the command line phpdoc but on the server I'm working on I can't install anything so the main question is : is it possible to generate the doc only with library uploaded on the server or does it necessarily needs a program to be installed ?

if no, do you know a librairy that could generate the doc ?

Furthermore, the 2 lines file phpdoc.php tells :

```
trigger_error('phpDocumentor2 should be run from the phpdoc file, not phpdoc.php', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
require_once __DIR__.'/phpdoc';
```

I've tryed to call this url : http://website.com/phpDocumentor-2.5.0/bin/phpdoc but it displays its content and does not execute it (obviously cause it does not have the php extension ...)

so ... well, I used to think a php library should be available as a php web service but I'm perhaps wrong ! tell me what you think about it ...

thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

phpDocumentor2 is solely a command-line program... it's not built to run via webserver.